# excel formulae within =IF

Tags: excel, if-statement

im trying to include a formulae within an =IF in excel, my formulae is:

```
=IF(AA5<Z5,=SLN(k5,y5,1),"Salvage")
```

The formula is designed to calculate straight line depreciation, AA5 is the assets age in years Z5 is its useful life. K5 is cost, Y5 is salvage value.

Im trying to achieve IF (Useful life is less than Age) then (Calculate Straight line deprecitation for year 1) else "Salvage"

I would then replicate the exact formulae changing the 1 in the =sln formulae for a 2, 3, 4, 5 in the next 4 cells to show either the current value or the word salvage for year 1,2,3,4,5

Both formulaes (=IF / =SLN) work perfectly independently but when i combine them this isn't working

It would help enormously if there could be a further test that checks that the useful life cell Z5 is less than or equal to the depreciation year (the last number in the =SLN formulae and if not also returns "Salvage"

Comment: Remove the `=` inside the expression.

Comment: That has worked perfectly - thank you!! so as a final improvement how would i modify the formulae so that the value returned by the formulae is never less than the salvage value (cell Y5)

Comment: use the max() function : max(sln(k5,y5,1),y5) should work,- tested and works(when I get my numbers in the right place...)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner (S Nelson) may do so too.. ( :